# Can an index improve performance when all the rows of the table are being used for an aggregation?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, aggregate-functions

In the last month, I've been trying to improve the execution time of a SQL Server stored procedure, used by the company that I work for, in an attempt to reduce the time of an extract created in tableau.

The problem is that this query targets millions of rows in a DWH and added to that, the query does aggregations on this data.

Creating indexes for the DWH table is not an option, so I thought that since the stored procedure uses temporal tables, I could create indexes on these.

But, after hours trying and testing the performance, I haven't been able to achieve my goal.

This is the first time that I need to apply indexes on a table, and even do I've read a lot about them, I still find some trouble understanding the complexity of indexing a table, also, I haven't found a similar scenario.

What I want to know is: if some kind of index could be applied on a temporal table, with a query that does aggregations grouping by all the columns that exist on that table.

Here is the example code:

```
SELECT 
    A.College,
    A.Department,
    A.CourseNumber,
    A.Subject,
    A.CourseSimple,
    A.Section,
    A.AcademicYear,
    A.Term,
    A.TermBeginDate,
    A.Item,
    A.CourseItemGroup,
    A.FullDate,
    A.WeekLevel,
    B.Instructor,
    SUM(A.Minutes) 'Minutes',
    COUNT(Distinct A.UserKey) 'Students',
    SUM(A.Items) 'Items'
FROM 
    #TT2 A
INNER JOIN 
    #TT3 B ON A.RowNumber = B.RowNumber
GROUP BY 
    A.College,
    A.Department,
    A.CourseNumber,
    A.Subject,
    A.CourseSimple,
    A.Section,
    A.AcademicYear,
    A.Term,
    A.TermBeginDate,
    A.Item,
    A.CourseItemGroup,
    A.FullDate,
    A.WeekLevel,
    B.Instructor
```

I would like to apply the index on #TT2.

Comment: `grouping by all the columns that exist on that table` - are you sure that everything is fine with data and query logic here?

Comment: Based on the query, the only indices that occur to me would be on RowNumber on TT2 and TT3.  Since this is in a DWH, though, have you considered pre-calculating this data during the warehouse load?

Comment: @IvanStarostin Yes, that's the way that the company needs to do the calculations, based on all the columns.

Comment: @Brian Actually, I've tried indexing by RowNumber, but without any performance change. I did a clustered unique index. Maybe i should use other type of index on RowNumber?

Comment: @Brian I forgot to say that i have not considered pre-calculating, that should be something to talk with the DBA.

Comment: `grouping by all the columns that exist on that table` - what did you store all those **duplicate** rows into that table for? Again, you are facing troubles with temp table which is **too big** to work fast, but you filled it yourself with data which, as you clearly knew before filling this table, must be **grouped**. Why don't you move all those **totally duplicate rows (13 columns!)** into separate temp table with **distinct** values only?

Comment: @Ivan I really didn't create the stored procedure, i was assigned to modify it and improve it by my boss, this was the work of someone else who is no longer around. But what i can tell you, is that for the calculations that need to be shown in tableau, i must grab those columns from the DWH, make some previous joins in the same SP (whit other temp tables) and by the end of the SP, do the calculations that i'm showing in the example code that i posted.

Answer (score -1):

No matter what, you have to read each row of data to get the information you are looking for. The only way to make this faster would be to make a **covering index**, one that contains all of the fields that you need to retrieve, mostly in the `INCLUDE` statement. This create statement would look something like this:

```
CREATE INDEX Idx_Covering ON #tt2 (RowNumber)
INCLUDE (
    College,
    Department,
    CourseNumber,
    Subject,
    CourseSimple,
    Section,
    AcademicYear,
    Term,
    TermBeginDate,
    Item,
    CourseItemGroup,
    FullDate,
    WeekLevel,
    Minutes,
    UserKey,
    Items
    )
```

Depending on your current indexing, you may want to make the index Unique. You can also try a CLUSTERED INDEX on Rownumber, but the covering index is usually faster in my experience.

Comment: I actually tried creating a Clustered Unique Index on RowNumber, but without any effect on the performance. But i haven't tried this Covering Index approach, i'll try it and see if it works.